# Why can't my setup.py-generated script find my also-installed module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools

**EDIT:** The exact code is on GitHub at https://github.com/edbrannin/mkdocs/tree/windows-runnable and it also fails on Linux.

---

I'm trying to make the script installation for [mkdocs](http://www.mkdocs.org/) cross-platform by using the `entry_points` argument to `setup()`:

`entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'mkdocs = mkdocs.mkdocs:main_entry_point',
            ],
        },`

[The output from `python setup.py install` is here.](https://gist.github.com/edbrannin/8093c6b708d4d7d59a7c)

Running `python setup.py install` produces `c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mkdocs` and this file in `c:\Python27\Scripts\mkdocs-script.py`:

```
#!C:\Python27\python.exe
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'mkdocs==0.9','console_scripts','mkdocs'
__requires__ = 'mkdocs==0.9'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('mkdocs==0.9', 'console_scripts', 'mkdocs')()
    )
```

When I try to run mkdocs, it says it can't find the module:

`C:\>mkdocs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\mkdocs-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('mkdocs==0.9', 'console_scripts', 'mkdocs')()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources.py", line 343, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources.py", line 2307, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources.py", line 2013, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named mkdocs`

...but it's clearly there:

```
C:\>python
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mkdocs
>>>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I would try updating distribute in your system, you seem to have older version installed. Not sure it would help, but there is some chance.

Comment: I just tried that; no dice.

Comment: Did you update to a new version of setuptools, or remain with distribute? You should probably do the former.

Comment: Also, you might want to include the contents of mkdocs' egg-info directory. An odd thought - is there a mkdocs.py script in C:\Python27\Scripts? That might mess things up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script location does indeed not exist. Your setup.py specifies mkdocs.mkdocs. main_entry_point, but that is not importable. You can check this you in your python shell:

```
>>> from mkdocs.mkdocs import main_entry_point
```

This will result in an import error. This happens because of a file naming error: if you rename mkdocs/mkdocs to mkdocs/mkdocs.py you should see things start working.

Comment: Thank you for answering here [too](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2014-June/024452.html)!  I hadn't paid much attention to the missing extension because it was originally a scripts=[...] file like "bin/mkdocs" and I was trying to change as little as possible with my first pull-request on that project.